# How to get real time keyboard frame while using keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

so my situation is as follows: I have a collectionView which loads chat messages, and an inputBarView that contains a textview, a send button, and some buttons (text, photo, etc). Currently, I'm using notifications to track the keyboard as it appears and hides, and modify the inputBarView's bottom constraint to keep it on top of the keyboard. What I'm trying to implement is for the user to be able to swipe away the keyboard akin to how facebook an imessage do it (gif 1).

[Gif 1 - the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZfRW.gif)

Currently, if I set the keyboardDismissMode to .interactive and keep the notification handler, the keyboard follows the user's finger as it slides down (as it's supposed to), but the inputBarView doesn't move until the keyboard is hidden (gif 2).

[Gif 2 - the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZe5.gif)

I have searched for a solution for this for the past couple of days but nothing has worked so far. There are multiple questions about this exact issue here, but they're all either outdated, workaround hacks, or pod recommendations. Is there way to track the keyboards frame while dismissing it using .interactive?